# Wordpress Post and Security Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, security, post, phpmyadmin

I am working with a wordpress database from a website that has been hacked and at the moment i am focusing on **wp_posts** table.

In phpmyadmin the **wp_posts** table from **mysql** has **17500** entrys and in the wordpres admin panel i see **3100** posts and **10** pages.When i search in phpmyadmin some of them are duplicated with different post dates but not showing in the wp-admin posts.The duplicate ones in phpmyadmin on the post_name column appear "4942-revision-v1" where 4942 is the ID for the first post of that duplicate group (they appear in pair of 3 or 4).

In the wp-admin posts some of them cannot be viewd, i can edit them but when i wanna see them through permalink it returns " **Oops! That page can’t be found.**". I tried to see some of them changeing the **ID** from permalink (ex: localhost/wordpress/?id=**3731** ) but all of them send me to the same page, the blog type with next and previous.

I mention the fact that at the start i tried to simulate the entire website locally but had a lot of problems with all the corrupted files from it, so i made a fresh install and imported the **wp_posts** table from the old one to the fresh new one (i am using a default theme **Twenty Sixteen** but cleaning it up)

For the security part i made a scan with **Exploit Scanner** and i found a ton of useless scripts with ads and other types.

After I finish with Exploit Scanner I will try **Sucuri/WoddFence/Anti-Malware/Centrora** for scans.I searched the web for a plugin that could scan for **sql injection** but didn't find something good....

I am hoping to find some guidance with those issues, allthough they might seem easy but are making me a lot nerves ^^.

Thanks !

Comment: They are auto saved posts and wp has done that for post recovering options. Don't worry, they are not spams or hacked ones

Comment: So, in order for the problematic posts to  appear i should delete the ones with ('ID'-revision-v1) ? Is it safe to delete them ? and how can i prevent auto save from duplicating ?

Comment: There are several plugins to cleanup revisions. To disable auto-save, please see this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/turning-off-autosave

Comment: Thanks for the advice, about the security issues, some advice about how could i clean it up or some plugins that might work for me in my situation or for the future hacks ? For security measures i will add captcha on comments and allow connection on wp-admin only for some IP's and maybe woodfence as a firewall and IP blocking.

Comment: Hacked site questions are off topic on SO.

Comment: So where should I adress about this matter ?